# Slideshow with automatic update

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentations, slideshow, automatic-update, libreoffice-impress

A slideshow that displays lists, taken from a spreadsheet, is to be run the whole day, looping continuously.
Whenever the data in that spreadsheet changes, the slideshow should pick these changes up and display them; it is ok if that happens after some time, or at the start of the next loop.

Is Powerpoint or Impress or whatever capable of doing this, with or without external tools? Preferably on a Linux platform, but Windows is ok too.